# Do not log successful apache requests

Tags: logging, apache2

I want to get rid of superfluous logging in Apache. I've find [tutorial](https://www.virtualhelp.me/applications/54-web-servers/746-apache-do-not-log) how to use [setenvif module](https://www.howtoforge.com/setenvif_apache2) for that purpose, setting variable `dontlog`.

The only problem is, I don't see on the criteria list what is the most interesting for me, the http status.

I'd like to do the following:

```
SetEnvIf Http_Status 200 dontlog
```

But it seems, there's no `Http_Status` support for `SetEnvIf`...

How to filter logs based on http status?

Comment: The `setenvif` module simple does not have an option to match the status code. You will have to look at other modules.

Answer (score 5):

A little bit of googling showed me the following [result](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/apache-don%27t-log-404-errors-789104/):

> Per status code differentiation
>   We all like HTTP status 200. It means 'OK' and that's why we're not interested in loging it. Most common situation is when we are looking for some specific status code in the logs. With `mod_log_config` you may create separate logs for every needed status. Please look at this configuration:

```
CustomLog ok.log "%200t %200a,%200{User-Agent}i %200U%200q %200s"
CustomLog redirections.log "%301t %301a,%301{User-Agent}i %301U%301q %301s"
CustomLog not_found.log "%404t %404a,%404{User-Agent}i %404U%404q %404s"
CustomLog server_error.log "%500t %500a,%500{User-Agent}i %500U%500q %500s"
```

It contains a link to [this website](http://helicontech.blogspot.com/2009/04/modlogconfig-capabilities.html).

## Edit:

The (current) [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html) of `mod_log_config` shows options for matching status codes:

> Particular items can be restricted to print only for responses with specific HTTP status codes by placing a comma-separated list of status codes immediately following the "%". The status code list may be preceded by a "!" to indicate negation.

So I suggest you read through that page and configure `CustomLog` configurations that suit your needs. I would start with trying something like:

```
CustomLog /dev/null "%200"
```

Though the file name must be relative to the `ServerRoot` so some trickery will be required there. Perhaps check some `chroot` documentation on how to copy the file /dev/null to inside your `ServerRoot`.

Comment: It looks like a third party extension, being a part of some separate product, with no licencing information or installation instruction for the module only.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This expression, worked for me: (Apache v2.4.52)

```
CustomLog /var/log/not_200.log vhost_combined "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} != 200"
```